# Stub a helper method from request spec - rspec3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, request, rabl, rspec3

I'm trying to write a request spec for my api. I'm using Rspec 3.

I want to stub a method in `ApplicationHelper`.  I'm using [rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) to render my api JSON.

This is the setup

```
#ApplicationHelper
module ApplicationHelper
  ...
  def preview_url
  end
  ...
end
```

I'm calling `preview_url` method from my `rabl` file. Problem is, since I'm using `request spec` I dont have access to `helper` method given my rspec `view specs`

Following is my spec so far

```
#spec/request/recipe_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'
require 'spec_helper'

describe Recipe, 'when viewing the recipe', type: :request,  focus: true do
  ...
  before do
    helper = Object.new.extend(ApplicationHelper)

    allow(helper).to receive(:preview_url).and_return("image.gif")
  end

  it 'some test' do
    ...
  end 
end
```

However, this will not stub the actual method in the `ApplicationHelper`.

Following I tried without success

```
allow(ApplicationHelper).to receive(:preview_url).and_return("image.gif") -> doesn't work  

allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationHelper).to receive(:preview_url).and_return("image.gif") -> will not work obviously because application helper is a module
```

How can I stub ApplicationHelper method from my request spec?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're just looking to stub a helper method instead of testing the helper itself, you can use `view`

```
  before { allow(view).to receive(:preview_url).and_return('image.gif') }

  it 'some test' do
    render
    expect(rendered).to match /Expected Output/
  end
```

[Relish Documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/view-specs/view-spec#passing-view-spec-that-stubs-a-helper-method)

Comment: thanks for the answer, however `view` is not available since this is a request spec `spec/requests/*` (I tried and now working)

Comment: Instead of defining `helper = Object.new.extend(ApplicationHelper)`, can you try just adding `include ApplicationHelper` inside your `describe` block and rerunning the `allow_any_instance_of` variant?